# Export data from NIntegrate and Piecewise

Tags: numerical-integration, export, piecewise

I use the following to calculate my Integral.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

G[ω_, τC_] := Exp[τC Sqrt[1 + ω^2] (1 - ω^2)]

position[x_] := Module[{xx = SetPrecision[x, 20]},
  -2 (mSlope/(α π)) Exp[α xx] NIntegrate[
     G[ω, τC] Cos[
        2 τC ω Sqrt[1 + ω^2] - 
         2 ArcTan[ω] + α xx ω]/(1 + ω^2), {\
ω, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] + 2 mSlope xx]

positionLeft[x_] := Module[{xx = SetPrecision[x, 20]},
  -2 (mSlope/(α π)) Exp[α xx] NIntegrate[
    G[ω, τC] Cos[
       2 τC ω Sqrt[1 + ω^2] - 
        2 ArcTan[ω] + α xx ω]/(1 + ω^2), \
{ω, 0, ∞}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]]

W[x_] := Piecewise[{{position[x], x >= 0}, {positionLeft[x], x < 0}}]

τC = 1*^-6; α = 10^-3; mSlope = 1/5;
```

I Would like to save `W[x_]` for every `x` from -250 to 250. I have tried `Export["result.txt",W[k_],{k,-200,200}]` but it does not save. How do I save the data such that first column is `x` and second is `W[x_]`. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I Would like to save W[x_] for every x from -250 to 250

See if this works for you. V 12.1

```
 data = W[#] & /@ Range[-2, 2];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
 Export["result.txt", data, "List"]
```

The result.txt file in same folder as the notebook looks like

[image]

One way to read it back is

```
  databack = Import["result.txt", "List"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  (databack - data) // Chop
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I have V12.0, and data = W[#] & /@ Range[-2, 2] gives me further output of NInt will be supressed during this calc

Comment: @newstudent it works for me on V 12.0 also, all on windows 10. Try with **clean kernel**. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OY31w.png)

Comment: @newstudent sorry, I do not understand. This is your code I run. You said range -250..250. So just change `Range[-2, 2]` in the example I posted to `Range[-250, 250]`. I do not know what values they will produce.