# Export data in multiple columns

Tags: functions, export, data

Let's say I have a function `W[x_]`; and would like to export the data for `xrange -100 to 100`

I have tried this

```
Result=W[#] & /@Range[-100,100];
Export = ["result,txt",Result,"List"]
```

Eg: 
The output I get:

```
    w[x_]
    -1.0
    -1.5
    -2.0
```

But I would like to save the `x_` values as the first column and `w[x_]` as the second column

```
 x_      w[x_]
 -100      -1.0
 -99       -1.5
 -98       -2.0
 ...        ....
 100       5.0
```

How does one print `x_` values too ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code in   [Export data from NIntegrate and Piecewise](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222372/export-data-from-nintegrate-and-piecewise) this is how to do it

```
 data = {#, W[#]} & /@ Range[-2, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now save it using the same commands in the above answer

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Export["result.txt", data, "List"]
```

Change the `Range` command above to whatever you want.